# Expose Redux store api using webpack instead of global

Tags: reactjs, webpack, redux, react-redux

I'm working on a react-redux application that has an api allowing devs to get information/set information about the current state of the store. Currently, the api is initialized after the store has been created and set as a global variable in the middleware:

```
...case INIT_API:
    global.appApi = applicationApi(action.payload);
```

where `applicationApi` is a factory function that receives the store and returns the api methods.

```
function applicationApi(store) {
    return {
        methodOne():...
```

This lets you make calls to the api in the browser dev console (`appApi.methodOne()`).

Here is my question: I am trying to figure out how to achieve this using webpack to expose the api instead of creating a global variable. Is this possible/any tips on execution would be much appreciated.

Comment: May be, window.appApi = ... ? Cannot image another way to make var usable from console, and by the way why don't you like your own way?

Comment: About Redux - it is not a good idea to put functions to redux store, as it makes store non-serializable

Comment: I am so confused... what is the point of doing this? Just so you can console.log the Redux store state?

Comment: The application is a product builder, so by 'store' I mean the state of the current product being customized.

Comment: Check `expose-loader`. The redux code feels weird to me, but that might do it.